# Alternate through lambda functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, lambda

I have to make a function that takes a list and and maps two lambda functions alternatively. Like this:

```
>>> alternateMap(lambda x: x+1, lambda y: y+10, [1, 2, 3, 4])
[2, 12, 4, 14]
```

So, the first function `lambda x: x+1` applies to the first element and the third element, the second function `lambda y: y+10` applies to the second and fourth elements.

So far I have this:

```
def alternateMap(function1, function2, l):
    for i in l:
        a = map(function1, l)
        i += 2
    for n in l[1:]:
        a = map(function2, l)
        i += 2
 return a
```

But unfortunately it's not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for any number of functions.

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> func_cycle = cycle([lambda x:x+1, lambda y:y+10])
>>> [next(func_cycle)(item) for item in [1, 2, 3, 4]]
[2, 12, 4, 14]
```

You stated in comments elsewhere that you need a version that uses `map`.  Here you go:

```
import itertools

class callable_cycle(itertools.cycle):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        return next(self)(*args, **kwds)

func_cycle = callable_cycle([lambda x:x+1, lambda y:y+10])
map(func_cycle, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```